# How do I show non-published items on the Content Management server when not logged in?

Tags: content-management

I have a content delivery server and a content management server.  On the content management server I want visitors to be able to see non-published items when they are not logged into Sitecore.

If I change the connection string for Web to Master I can see the non-published items obviously, but then I cannot publish as it tries to publish from Master to Master.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to run your CM instance in [**Live Mode**](http://www.verndale.com/insights/blog/2012/october/sitecore-live-mode/).

Running a site in Live Mode means that it reads items directly from the Master database. At the same time, your `web` connection string is preserved and you are still able to publish from Master to Web.

To enable the Live Mode, go to `App_Config/Include` and rename the file `LiveMode.config.example` to `LiveMode.config`.

Additionally, if you have other site definitions apart from `website`, you'll need to update them as well by modifying the `LiveMode.config`. For example, if you have a custom site definition named "mySite", your `LiveMode.config` might look like this:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <sites>
      <site name="website">
        <patch:attribute name="database">master</patch:attribute>
        <patch:attribute name="filterItems">true</patch:attribute>
      </site>
      <site name="mySite">
        <patch:attribute name="database">master</patch:attribute>
        <patch:attribute name="filterItems">true</patch:attribute>
      </site>
    </sites>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 5):

There are a number of ways to go about this - it depends a little bit on how ambitious you want to be with this.

One way is to configure a new site on your CM server (a Sitecore site definition), make it respond to a different host name (so preview.cm.internal or whatever). Sitecore includes `Livemode.Config.example` to show how this can be set up.

Another way to go about it, is to set up a [Preview Publishing Target](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/content_authoring/publishing/preview_and_setup/walkthrough_publishing_items_to_a_preview_publishing_target).

Essentially this will allow you to set up publishing of your site to a dedicated *publishing target*, even when not everything in workflows is in "final" state.

### Adding a new Publishing Target

Add your new target under `/sitecore/system/publishing targets`, make sure to mark it as a "preview publishing target".

[image]

Optionally, also configure any workflows you use, to allow publishing to this target even when not "final".

[image]

References:

- [Walkthrough: Publishing items to a preview publishing target](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/content_authoring/publishing/preview_and_setup/walkthrough_publishing_items_to_a_preview_publishing_target)
- [Executive Preview And Publishing Related Items](http://getfishtank.ca/blog/2-big-improvements-to-publishing-in-sitecore-7)

Comment: Thanks for the through explanation. I went with the more simple route as our current setup (not a typical Sitecore installation) is setup to view Master items on our "preview" server without our users having to publish.